# How to run a local proxy behind a VPN?

Tags: vpn, firefox, socks

#### The Problem

Accessing VPN-unfriendly sites without turning off the VPN.

#### Background

When connected, my VPN provides me with multiple `socks5` proxy endpoints. Combine that with [Firefox containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) and in a couple of clicks I can have a *new tab* in another city, country, continent...

Sometimes though, specially when shopping, I can't use a VPN. In these situations I would like to simply create a new tab that bypasses the VPN, kinda like Tail's unsafe browser (but in a single container).

#### Solutions?

The ideal solution would be a local proxy, i.e. a proxy running on localhost that routes traffic through the network interface connected to my router, and not the VPN interface.

Ideal:

```
wlan0 |-> wg0 -> socks -> destination (VPN IP)
      |-> socks -> destination (ISP IP)
```

Not ideal:

- Buying residential proxies, since I don't feel comfortable about the possibility of piggybacking on a zombie somewhere.
- Setting up a local proxy on my router, since it wouldn't be portable, unless I opened it to the internet which wouldn't be advisable because it hasn't received a firmware update in years.
- Turning off the VPN or [Wireproxy](https://github.com/pufferffish/wireproxy), since it would leak too much traffic in the background (DNS, cron, Tor).

#### Setup

I'm running `wpa_supplicant` with NetworkManager on Debian 12.